# How do I get the cartesian product of 2 vectors by using Iterator?

Tags: rust

I have 2 `Vec`s:

```
let x = vec!['1', '2', '3'];
let y = vec!['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Now I want to use iterator to make a new vec like this `['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2b', '2c', '3a', '3b', '3c']`. How can I do?

Comment: Why not simply two loops, one inside the other one ?

Comment: I'm learning about iterator, so I want to do it to understand how it works

Comment: I edited the title because it wasnt correct. Pairing would mean to the pairs of matching indexes values, aka `zip`. From your example what you really want is the ***cartessian product***

Comment: This is so weird that it can't be done with `std::iter::Product`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how to do it with vanilla Rust iterators:

```
fn main() {
    let x = vec!['1', '2', '3'];
    let y = vec!['a', 'b', 'c'];
    let product: Vec<String> = x
        .iter()
        .map(|&item_x| y
            .iter()
            .map(move |&item_y| [item_x, item_y]
                .iter()
                .collect()
                )
            )
        .flatten()
        .collect();
    
    println!("{:?}", product);
}
```

### Explanation

The easiest way to construct a `String` from two `chars` is to `collect` iterator over the `chars`:

```
let string: String = [item_x, item_y].iter().collect();
```

For each item in `x` we iterate over `y` and construct such string.

```
x.iter().map(|&item_x| y.iter.map(move |&item_y| ...));
```

We use pattern matching to get value in the `map` closure rather then references. Because of that and the fact that the `char` has `Copy` trait, we can `move` `item_x` into inner closure, resolving any lifetime issues.

As the result of the code above we get an iterator over iterators over `String`s. To flatten that iterator, we use `flatten` method (who would think?). Then we collect the flat iterator into the resulting `Vec`.

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf2987ed96303a0db0f629884492011e

Answer (score 14):

Easiest way would be to use the ***[cartesian product](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/macro.iproduct.html)*** macro available in the `itertools` crate

```rust
use itertools::iproduct; // 0.10.1

fn main() {
    let x = vec!['1', '2', '3'];
    let y = vec!['a', 'b', 'c'];
    let product: Vec<String> = iproduct!(x, y)
        .map(|(a, b)| format!("{}{}", a, b))
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", product);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e0e43348a42d2e7efc53f4c8be482e79)

Answer (score 5):

The existing answers make sense if your goal is to get the Cartesian product of two iterators. If you've got vectors or slices already though (like in the original question) you can do a little better:

```
fn main() {
    let x = vec!['1', '2', '3'];
    let y = vec!['a', 'b', 'c'];
    let result: Vec<String> = product(&x, &y)
        .map(|(a, b)| format!("{}{}", a, b))
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", result)
}

fn product<'a: 'c, 'b: 'c, 'c, T>(
    xs: &'a [T],
    ys: &'b [T],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&'a T, &'b T)> + 'c {
    xs.iter().flat_map(move |x| std::iter::repeat(x).zip(ys))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=85c972d2ac329fe341c26696db7d8538)

Any iterator based solution will necessarily require storing the full contents of the iterator somewhere, but if you already have the data in a vector or array you can use the known size to only store the indices instead.

Comment: Can't it be done more easily with something that looks like this?
    `xs.flat_map(|x| repeat(x).zip(ys))`

Comment: @feature_engineer - that is absolutely a more elegant version. I'll update my answer.