# Rust "combine" iterators?

Tags: rust, iterator

I am curious if rust has some buildin function to combine iterators aka. "every element from A with every element from B". Similar how haskell handles `[(x,y)| x <- [1..3], y <- [3..6]]`

```rust
    let t = (1..3)
        .into_iter()
        ."combine"((3..6) //Magic goes here?
            .into_iter())
        .collect::<Vec<usize>>();
    assert_eq!(t, vec![(1,3),(2,3),(1,4),(2,4)....]);
```

Thanks :D

Comment: The word you're looking for is the "cartesian product" of iterators.

Comment: Other related questions: [How do I get the cartesian product of 2 vectors by using Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69613407/11082165), [How to create a function that creates a Cartesian product Iterator from an Iterator of Iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47668915/11082165)